# ios 7 unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary, afnetworking-2

i am getting error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xca51f70" The app crashes at the line "
 daysWeather = eventsJSONData[indexPath.row];" I read several posts on the issue and understand that is an NSArray / NSDictionary setting error. I just can't seem to figure out what it is that I need to change. Let me know if there is any other code I can post. Thanks for the help.

Relevant code is below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(!self.events)
        return 0;

    NSArray *eventsJSONData = [self.events eventsJSONData];
    return [eventsJSONData count];
    NSLog( @"the count is %lu", (long)[eventsJSONData count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    TDCell *cell = (TDCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TDCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"EventCell"];
    }
    NSDictionary *daysWeather = nil;

    NSArray *eventsJSONData = [self.events eventsJSONData];
    daysWeather = eventsJSONData[indexPath.row];

    [cell configCell:daysWeather];

    return cell;
}
```

The json object displays as the code below in the debug area:

```
2014-09-12 03:19:45.660 iCLUB[24624:60b] JSON OWNER: {
data =     {
    events =         {
        result =             (
                            {
                "end_time" = "4:00AM";
                "event_date" = "09-12-2014";
                "event_id" = 84;
                "event_image" = "http://www.asadfdfs.com/iclub/images/event_flyers/event114105121486dd4697f899124d1c3519c0f2272710f.png";
                "event_price" = 20;
                "event_tickets_total" = 200;
                "event_title" = "New Test Event";
                "start_time" = "1:00AM";
                "venue_name" = "the box";
                weekday = Friday;
            }
        );
    };
};
}
```

Comment: What selector is the unrecognized one? You should get that error aswell.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...At the bottom it then prints eventsJSONData which is the json object above and description of indexPath:
<NSIndexPath: 0xc9c7780> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

Comment: Is your deployment target iOS 5 or earlier?

Comment: Deployment target is 7.1

Comment: -1 (and a vote to close) for not providing the COMPLETE exception message and the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this line

```
NSArray *eventsJSONData = [self.events eventsJSONData];
```

should change to that (or something similar)

```
NSArray *eventsJSONData = [self.events eventsJSONData][@"result"];
```

From your JSON object seems that `self.events` returns a dictionary with one key @"result".

Comment: wow thanks alot that fixed the issue. I still don't understand the reasoning behind it in this case. Thanks anyways though, i had spent a couple of hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: While this answer may "work" it's not technically correct.  See my answer for correctness.